# Chunk text files with BASH

Tags: bash, grep, zip, tail, unix-head

I am relatively new to Bash and I would like to chunk a txt contained in a zip file. The chunk must be from 5 lines up from "channel8" to  2 lines up from "channel10"

```
12082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
Channel8
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
Channel9
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
Channel10
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
Channel11
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
```

So far I have only succeed to chunk up to channel 10, see below:

```
12082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
Channel8
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
Channel9
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
Channel10
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
```

but I do not know how to use my bash output to select from channel 8.

This is my code

```
for file in ./*.zip; do head -$(($(unzip -c $file | grep -n $channel_after | cut -f1,1 -d":")-1)) <(unzip -c $file);done
```

Comment: Post the expected output. It's not clear when you say "up to channel 10" is you mean "up to the line that contains the string `channel10`" or "up to the end of the block that starts with the line `channel10`" or something else so different people are making different assumptions in their answers.

Answer (score 1):

Would `sed` do the job?

```
unzip -c $file | sed -n '/Channel8/,/Channel10/p'
```

That `sed` command will print everything between `Channel8` and `Channel10`, including the `Channel` lines.

If you don't want the `Channel` lines included you could use another `sed` to delete rather than print.

```
unzip -c $file | sed '1,/Channel8/d;/Channel10/,$d'
```

Comment: Thanks! What If I would like to chunk 4 lines up from Channel8 and 2 lines up from Channel10? Consider now that the word channel is not at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score -1):

it sounds like what you need is:

```
unzip -c "$file" |
    awk '
        /^Channel8$/ { seenBeg = 1 }

        seenBeg {
            if ( seenEnd && /^Channel/ ) {
                exit
            }
            else if ( /^Channel10$/ {
                seenEnd = 1
            }
            print
        }
    '
```